# Is there a way to see valid tiles for settlement?

Tags: civilization-5

In the game, there are suggested sites for settlement with the golden icon, but is there a way to see which titles are valid or invalid for establishing a new city? The restriction of neighboring cities is not always clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the wiki:

> Cities have to be at least 4 tiles apart of each other. That includes your cities, as well as other civilizations' cities, and it prevents littering the map with cities. Other than that, cities may be found on any tile where a Settler unit may move to (including a 1-tile island).

Basically, using this rule manually gives you a general idea of where to settle in proximity to other cities, but there is no interface built into the game that I am aware of to warn you of your city's proximity to different city's, other than having a settler at the spot you wish to settle. This information should be enough though for your purposes.

More information can be found here: http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Settling_a_city_%28Civ5%29

Comment: That "4 tiles apart" is actually a bit misleading, or at least ambiguous. It actually means there must be at least _three_ tiles between the city tiles. Technically, if you count from the tile centre, the distance between the cities is four tiles. But I think most of the people would count that as three tiles, not four. (Of course, the original writer of that sentence could just have written incorrectly.)

Comment: I believe you are correct in saying that. This is from a fan made wiki, so all information may not be explicit.

Comment: I now checked a bit more. Actually the game itself gives an error "Cannot found a City within 4 Tiles of another city". But still, as anyone can go and try themselves, two cities must only have three tiles between them. The error message is quite confusing and perhaps just wrong in itself as well.

Also, if you found a city on another continent (i.e. any land mass completely separated by water, even one tile island), the cities must have only _two_ tiles between, which is even more confusing. Perhaps the original restriction actually was four tiles, but was changed later.

Comment: @synchronos Interesting. In my own game play, I just use 4 apart as a rule of thumb, but there are certainly exceptions to the rule. As a casual player, I don't really try to exploit the rules of the game, and it fits my play style well, but I can see places when glitches could come in handy.

Comment: @synchronos I'd be interested to see a screenshot of that, my assumption was that the rule was basically that no city could have another city in its workable tiles range.

Comment: No problem. I played a test game before posting the comment, and here you go: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=375143422

Comment: Also what is notable that the city placement rule doesn't completely clear, if the settler is on a different island. They still require to have those two tiles - one is not enough - as can be seen from here: http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=375146332

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Rick_Roll's answer, You may accomplish this via `Mods`.

For example, I currently use this mod that does the exact thing you want: [***Civ5 - City Limits***](http://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=80071068)

It highlights tiles that are invalid for settlement when a city or settler is selected.